# Electromagnetic battery

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there anyway to transfer the electromagnetic energy of a naturally occurring magnet into usable electricity kinda like using the magnet as a battery?

Comment: Congrats, you've reinvented the [magnetic generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_magnet_synchronous_generator).

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way I know is to move a wire through the magnetic field thereby creating an electric current. You would need to provide energy to complete the movement of the wires.
The electricity generated could then be used to charge a battery. This is what a generator does.

I could go into some magnetic zero point set ups but that is frowned upon on this site. There are no free lunches. If you are interested in zero point energy magnetic set ups there are plenty on youtube.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an electromagnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

A magnet does not contain electromagnetic energy, rather, it just has a magnetic field, the force generated by that field on a particle is influenced by the charge and distance.  An electromagnet only occurs when there is moving current through a wire.
A magnet can certainly move electrons though a wire, but I believe this would be incredibly inefficient for any real practical application.  Just try to imagine a device this would be applied to, a flashlight, for example.  Using copper wire (which has electrons that can be moved quite "freely"), the magnet must be moved the distance of the wire quickly back and forth, resulting in even more work than the traditional battery.

Comment: There are a number of rechargeable flashlights on the market, where you charge the flashlight by shaking it. This moves an internal magnet through a coil of wire, generating current which charges the battery. It does take some work, though. But, that isn't what the OP meant; he wondered if the magnetic energy alone could cause usable current.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not a battery with a permanent ferromagnet which I think your word "natural" refers to.

You could build a battery with a coil of super conducting wire that has a load resistor (the circuit you wish to power) across it.  In parallel with the resistor is a power supply and a super conducting shorting switch that is initially open.  The power supply (through a big series resistor) is turned on and builds up the magnetic field.  Then the super conducting switch is closed, and the power supply turned off. Voila!  You have a charged battery that will remain charged until you open the super conducting switch.  The current will then flow through the load resistor until the magnetic field decreases to zero.  This is actually how big super conducting electromagnets work.

You could also use the energy in the permanent ferromagnet's field.  Wrap a coil of wire around the magnet and connect it to your load resistor.  Heat the magnet to above its Curie temperature.  As the B field goes away, it generates a voltage across your load resistor.  Now cool the magnet to below its Curie temperature.  As the domains realign themselves and the B field increases, again a voltage is generated across your load resistor.  Unfortunately, this is really a generator rather than a battery since the energy is ultimately coming from the heat source used to warm up the magnet.

Electric charges flow along the electric field lines created by a battery, can do work as they flow, and remove energy from the battery.  Magnetic charges (aka magnetic monopoles), if they existed, could similarly flow along magnetic field lines, presumably do work, and remove the stored B field from a permanent magnet.  Unfortunately, Maxwell's equation $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}=0$  means there are no magnetic charges, and none have been discovered.