# Magnetic harvesting

Tags: energy

(I asked a question earlyer and then I realized that I had worded it in the wrong way so I am going to try again) so I was wonder if it was possible to harvest the magnetic energy from a permanent magnet and convert that magnetic energy into electricity? because I know energy can't be created or destroyed it can only change it's form and I know that you can use electricity to create a magnetic field

I apologize ahead of time for the lack of technical terms and the bad grammar

Comment: Please see the answers to your last question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214412/electromagnetic-battery which I think answer your new question.

Comment: The only energy you can "harvest" from a magnet is the energy that went into magnetizing it, which is probably no more than a few J per cubic centimeter of material for a modern magnetic material. Not sure why you would want to destroy a perfectly good and useful magnet for such a little bit of energy, though?